Testcontainers with Bitnami PostgreSql
I use Testcontainers with Bitnami PostgreSql docker image for integration tests. Container always crashes after I start running tests. I checked the container logs and saw these messages. What I can do about this?

public static class PostgreSqlSetup
{
    public static PostgreSqlContainer CreateContainer()
    {
        var container = new PostgreSqlBuilder()
            .WithImage("bitnami/postgresql:15.3.0")
            .WithUsername("postgres")
            .WithPassword("postgres")
            .Build();

        return container;
    }
}


Modules come pre-configured. For example, for PostgreSQL, we set fsync=off. It looks like that Bitnami's version does not support this configuration, or at least the entrypoint cannot handle it. To resolve this, simply use the generic builder instead of the module.
